# How to sort and change date format in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt5, c++14, qtableview

I've already implemented a `QTableView` + `QStandardItemModel` in Qt5. At the beginning, I set the date data just as a string with the date format based on the application setting. For instance, it can be the US format like `MM/dd/yyyy` or the european format `dd.MM.yyyy`. The data comes from a json file with the european date format. My first implementation was like this:

```
shared_ptr<QStandardItemModel> _model;
// detect a date string with regex, get the submatches and create a QDate object from it
QDate date(stoi(submatches[3].str()), stoi(submatches[2].str()), stoi(submatches[1].str()));

QModelIndex index = _model->index(rowPos, colPos, QModelIndex());
// depends on the setting, the date can be shown on the table like this
_model->setData(index, QString(date.toString("dd.MM.yyyy"));

// activate the column sorting in the QTableView
ui->tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
```

This implementation, however, cannot sort the date column correctly. The reason is because the QTableView sorts the column just like a string (sorted by day isntead of by year first) instead of a date entry.

I can change the implementation by setting the data directly with the date object:

```
_model->setData(index, date);
```

The sorting works perfectly by date. But, the format is now always shown in `dd/MM/yyyy` format.
How can I keep this sorting function, but change the date view depends on the date format setting?

I've read that it may be implemented using a custom subclass of `QAbstractTableModel`. How about implementing as a SubClass of `QTableView`? Or may be with a subclass of `QAbstractItemModel` like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40499163/5700318)? I'm not an expert yet to implement and integrate a Qt5 subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to pass the QDate as data to the model, and use a delegate to set as shown in the view:

```cpp
_model->setData(index, date);
```

```cpp
class DateDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate{
public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
    QString displayText(const QVariant &value, const QLocale &locale) const{
        return locale.toString(value.toDate(), "dd.MM.yyyy");
    }
};
```

```
ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(col_date, new DateDelegate);
```

Comment: thank you for your great solution! Could you send me a link to more details documentation that I can learn more about this possibility using delegate in general? Or may be some other examples

Comment: @ywiyogo See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html